# Execute shellcode by casting to function pointer in Visual C++

Tags: c++, casting, shellcode

In gcc this works fine. The code goes something like:

```
unsigned char b[50] = "\xda\xd1 ... \x0"; //some shellcode with terminating \x0
( (void(*)())b )(); //cast b to function pointer from void to void, then run it
```

But when this is put in Visual C++, it spits out this error message:

```
1>..\test.cpp(132): error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char [50]' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

Anyone know why this is so?

Comment: Even if you get this to work somehow, it's a very bad idea.

Comment: Or: `reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(static_cast<char*>(b))()`.

Comment: @NiklasB. `(*(void(*)())&b[0])()` crashes at runtime. First, &b[0] is the same as b. Second, the extra * at the beginning dereferences the function pointer; I assume that it then tries to interpret the shellcode as an address.

Comment: The wonder isn't that it crashes in Visual C++, the wonder is that it works in gcc. And what exactly do you mean by "shellcode"?

Comment: @user49164 dereferencing a function pointer is harmless. It quickly decays back into a function pointer. That's where the classical `***********************************fun_ptr` example comes from.

Comment: @user: You're wrong, it's not the same.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: It's the standard idiom for testing position-independent, self-contained machine code (shellcode).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A proper debugger will tell you what's going wrong. I can only guess that your code is causing an access violation because the buffer you want to jump to is not executable.

Probably you're on a default-[DEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention)-enabled system like Vista or 7, so you have to make sure that your shellcode is executable. To do that, first use `VirtualAlloc` to allocate a new, executable buffer and copy your shellcode into it, then execute it:

```
void *exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof b, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
memcpy(exec, b, sizeof b);
((void(*)())exec)();
```

By the way, you don't need to null-terminate the shellcode (C++ will terminate the string literal automatically for you, but this is not necessary). You also don't need to specify a size:

```
unsigned char b[] = "\xcc";
```

Comment: Thank you - this works properly. Didn't know that there was a special allocation function for executing stuff.

Comment: @user49164: To increase the difficulty of exploiting stack- and heap-based buffer overflows, DEP enforces the obedience of execution permissions on memory pages. This prevents the immediate execution of data on the stack or heap. `VirtualAlloc` is not a special allocation function for executing stuff, it's the general allocation function (which happens to take as an argument the desired access permissions of the allocated memory).

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to reinterpret data as a different type is by copying the binary representation:

```
void (*fp)();
unsigned char buf[50];
char const * p = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&buf);

std::copy(p, p + sizeof(char const *), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&fp));

// now fp contains the same value as &buf

fp();  // call
```

This avoids undefined behaviour caused by aliasing and alignment violations.

Comment: The OP is trying to reinterpret a pointer to the buffer as a function pointer, in order to execute the contents as code. Your version overwrites the function pointer with some of the buffer contents - the result is certainly not a valid pointer. You'll need to define a pointer to `buf`, then copy the value of that.

Comment: confirmed. This crashes at runtime.

Comment: This seems like it should work but it crashes - perhaps it's the same DEP problem?

Comment: Even in the edited form, this will only copy `sizeof(void*)` bytes.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Well, no, it'll copy `sizeof(char*)` bytes, which is precisely how many bytes there are at `&buf`. Nobody said this was guaranteed to make sense, and it's up to you to ensure that on your platform char pointers, void pointers and function pointers have the same size. You could add one (standard) conversion to void-pointer if you wanted to omit the first check (i.e. add a `void const * q = static_cast<void const *>(p);` and copy that one).